# Contacting service in kubernetes

Tags: python, mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I thought I understood how kubernetes services work, and have always seen them like a way to "group" several pods, in order to make it able to contact the service instead of the single pods. However, it seems like I am wrong. I created a mysql deployment (with only one pod) and a service in order to reach out to the service if I want to use the mysql connection from other pods(other microservices). This is the service I made:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    run: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: mysql
```

I hoped this would have allowed me to connect to the mysql pod by reaching the `<clusterIp>:<targetPort>`, but the connection is refused whenever I try to connect. I tried reading online and initially thought `nodeport` service type was a good idea, but the kubernetes website tells that the service is than reachable by `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>` so this got me confused. MySQL should be reachable only inside the cluster by other nodes. How can I make this happen?

###### NOTES:

- I am working on minikube.
- Here is how I try connecting from one pod to the mysql service on python:

```
service = api.read_namespaced_service(name="mysql", namespace="default")

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=service.spec.cluster_ip, user="root",
                                 password="password", database="db_name",
                                 auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/init/db_init.py", line 10, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=service.spec.cluster_ip, user="root",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 272, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1028, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 241, in _open_connection
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.107.203.112:3306' (111)
```

### UPDATE

As requested, here is the whole log of the mysql pod:

```
2022-01-27 17:57:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
2022-01-27 17:57:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-01-27 17:57:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
2022-01-27 17:57:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-01-27T17:57:15.090697Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2022-01-27T17:57:15.105399Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-01-27T17:57:16.522380Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-01-27T17:57:20.805814Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2022-01-27 17:57:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2022-01-27 17:57:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2022-01-27T17:57:29.868217Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 92
2022-01-27T17:57:29.892649Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-01-27T17:57:30.100941Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-01-27T17:57:30.398700Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-01-27T17:57:30.398743Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-01-27T17:57:30.419293Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-01-27T17:57:30.430833Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-01-27T17:57:30.430879Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-01-27 17:57:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2022-01-27 17:57:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database football

2022-01-27 17:57:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/SQL.sql


2022-01-27 17:57:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2022-01-27T17:57:33.143178Z 12 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.28).
2022-01-27T17:57:36.222404Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-01-27 17:57:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2022-01-27 17:57:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2022-01-27T17:57:37.329690Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 1
2022-01-27T17:57:37.336444Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-01-27T17:57:37.525143Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-01-27T17:57:37.738175Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-01-27T17:57:37.738216Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-01-27T17:57:37.745722Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-01-27T17:57:37.757638Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-01-27T17:57:37.757679Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Also, here is the deployment I used:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: repo/football-mysql
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

Comment: This line `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.107.203.112:3306' (111)` shows that the service is there (it resolves to an IP). Can you post the logs of `mysql` pods in case there is something wrong with it?

Comment: Sure! I don't really know how to read it, so I am posting the whole thing. Thank you very much for your help @pkaramol!

Comment: @anemyte yes. I am updating the post with the deployment

Comment: @anemyte sorry I am very new to kubernetes and do not really understand what I did wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: So I replace `run` with `app`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a label mismatch between the Service and the Pod:

```yaml
# service
spec:
  selector:
    run: mysql  # <- this
```

vs

```yaml
# deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql  # <- and this
```

Because of it, the Service targets some other Pod, not the one created by the Deployment. In other words, the Service looks for Pods with `run` label value equal to `mysql`, while your MySQL Pod has `app` label with `mysql` in it.

To make it work, at least one pair of labels has to be completely equal on both sides for the Service and the Pod. In this case, replacing `run` for `app` should be enough:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    run: mysql  # changing here isn't mandatory, up to you
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mysql  # here is the required change
```